# Error working with oracle db during build.xml from ant

Tags: java, oracle, ant

I want to add data to db oracle.

I am doing it with ant build.xml

When I start ant I get error:

jbuild.xml:961: java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

At 961 string in build.xml I see

```
    <sql
driver="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
classpath="${templateResources}/genericLibs/ojdbc14.jar"
url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@${ds_server}:${ds_sid}"
userid="@{user}"
password="@{password}"
output="drop.sql"
print="true"
showheaders="false"
showtrailers="false"
>
@{sql}
</sql>
```

Also I have properties file for ant with db properties

```
ds_server = localhost:1521
ds_sid = prd1
ds_username = test
ds_password = test
EXTds_username = test
EXTds_password = test
```

I am working in UNIX. How can I check my settings without ant or understand the problem reason?

Or where is I can read about it?

Thanks.

Comment: Is your listener actually running, and on localhost port 1521? `lsnrctl status` should tell you. You seem to be missing `$` before `{user}` and `{password}` but I don't think it's getting that far.

Comment: Thanks. I decided my issue. The problem was related with server name and sid.